# Decode function in codeigniter not working

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have done a code in codeigniter for login page where username and password are entered. After clicking submit button, the password is picked from the database and decoded but the decrypted password is not the original password.

It is showing another password with various symbols but not the original password.

```
$this->encrypt->decode($row['password'], ENC_KEY)
```

is not giving the original password. I have set the `encryption_key` in the config file and also called the library encrypt.

But still the decode function is not displaying the original password. why is it like that ?

I have given the constructor in the controller file as :

```
public function __construct() 
{
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('encrypt');
  $this->load->library('session');
  $this->load->model("loginmodel");
}
```

Comment: how you are getting ENC_KEY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

**First** way by using *config encryption key*

use `$this->config->item('encryption_key'`) to get config encryption key

```
$msg = 'password';
$key = $this->config->item('encryption_key');
$encrypted_data = $this->encrypt->encode($msg,$key);
echo $encrypted_data.PHP_EOL;

$original = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_data,$key);
echo $original;
```

**Second** : use own key if you don't want to use config encryption key

```
$msg = 'password';
$key = 'mykey';
$encrypted_data = $this->encrypt->encode($msg,$key);
echo $encrypted_data.PHP_EOL;

$original = $this->encrypt->decode($encrypted_data,$key);
echo $original;
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encrypt.html

Comment: How to create my own key ?

Comment: just like given  in my answer, key may in encrypted form or may be plain text just copy the code and check the result

Comment: ok use it with $this->config->item('encryption_key'); as given in my answer's first part

Comment: I have given the same code but the decode function is not working.

Comment: load your encrypt class with autoload.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171376/discussion-between-webdev-and-pradeep).

Comment: `$this->encrypt->decode($row['password'], ENC_KEY)` this is displaying a password with different symbols.Actually it should display 'admin'

Comment: I have given the full code of model file where decode func is used.

Comment: where you define ENC_KEY?

Comment: in the config file

Comment: and by the way for password encryption alway use hash method using password_hash instead of encode

Comment: i can only  $config['encryption_key'] = 'CAR_ENTRANCE'; not  ENC_KEY constant

Comment: i think that is why its not working for you , replace ENC_KEY  with $this->config->item('encryption_key'); in your decode method just like given in my answer's first portion